# Condition of having unusually high body temperature due to being exposed to harmful winds?

Tags: single-word-requests, medical

What's the word for the condition in which you have a unusually high body temperature after being exposed to harmful winds without proper clothing protection? It's as if the winds somehow got through your pores and made you sick.

Comment: As far as I know, fevers are caused by infections, which are caused by microorganisms, not "bad winds". There were theories about illness being caused by things like bad smells and night air before the era of modern medicine, but I've never heard of the condition you're describing in a contemporary context.

Comment: @1006a Wait, are you telling me unusually high body temperature isn't a symptom of fever? What is it then?

Comment: *Hyperthermia* (high body temperature) is a symptom of fever, but isn't synonymous with fever—for example, it can be caused by heat stroke or burning at the stake. *Fever* is a more specific thing, triggered by exposure to pathogens or a few other things like certain chemicals, but not just natural wind. You can read more here: http://www.avsspecialists.com/client-resources/articles/true-fever-versus-non-febrile-hyperthermia/

Comment: It's just sunburn that is obscured by the wind until it gets pretty bad. Severe hypothermia victims often say they feel hot and will try to remove clothing before they die. That's why you mustn't leave them alone.

Comment: The only way I can think of to get a high fever directly from harmful winds is to be exposed to radioactive fallout by wind.  See [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/radiation-sickness/basics/symptoms/con-20022901)

Comment: @1006a Oh I see. We only have one word to describe that state of health in our awfully lacking language. It doesn't matter what causes it, there's only one word. I guess that's why I was confused.

Comment: @1006a I'll have my stake med-rare, if you don't mind.

Comment: If you take a long walk in windy, chilly weather wearing not enough clothes, you will indeed get all flushed and feel very hot when you get back inside. That's not an illness, though, just your body adjusting to alternating temperatures and trying to keep your core temperature constant. I don't think there's a word for that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are thinking of "[hypothermia](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/hypothermia/basics/definition/con-20020453)" which is a loss of control of body temperature often leading to shivering and physical distress caused by excessive exposure to cold, rather than by exposure to pathogens, although your somewhat muddled understanding of what causes the condition and what its symptoms are is tripping you up. It actually involves the opposite of a fever, a too low body temperature rather than a too high body temperature, but doesn't feel like that to someone experiencing it.

A less medically precise and somewhat more old fashioned term, often used by news reporters, novelists, poets or crime investigators who don't know enough facts to medically diagnose the precise medical syndrome that someone experienced due to exposure to cold air is to say that someone suffered (or died) as a result of "**exposure**."

These terms are not to be confused with a "**cold**" which is a usually mild viral infection that can lead to a low grade fever, coughing and a runny nose. The name of this condition is a false friend based upon the mistaken and obsolete belief that these symptoms are caused directly by cold temperatures, when in fact, these symptoms are caused by a virus and are more common in months when temperatures are colder mostly because reduced humidity at those times makes people more vulnerable to infection with this virus (usually one of a large class of viruses called "rhino viruses" because the term rhino refers to the nose and these viruses give you a congested or runny nose).

The opposite of hypothermia, which occurs when someone has an elevated body temperature due to exposure to the sun or heat, rather than to a pathogen, is called a "**heat injury**", a term which includes both the more severe "[heat stroke](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/heat-stroke-symptoms-and-treatment#1)" and the less severe form of heat injury called "[heat exhaustion](http://www.medicinenet.com/heat_exhaustion/article.htm)."

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a term based on folklore. Such as "you'll catch your death out there" (in that wind).  There may be a precise term on the tip of your toungue that you cannot quite remember; at the same time I imagine there are many such terms that are localized and/or generational. Point is that it is not a scientific term in any manner and yet at the same time it Is a generic concept that most likely has many names.